# Is this possible to find the maximum of differentiable and analytic function on finite and fixed interval in O(1) time using quantum computer?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, quantum-computing

$f$ is differentiable (continous) and analytic function.

If $x\in\mathbb{R} \land 0\le x\le1$ then $f(x)$ is **computable**, $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\le f(x)\le1$.

I have a conjecture that it is possible in O(1) constant time to find the maximum of $f$ in the interval [0,1] by using quantum computer.

Let some qubit be the domain of $f$ and all the values of $x$ where $0\le x\le1$ call this qubit *"input"* and there is quantum circuit that implements $f$.

At last we need another qubit to be the range of $f$ and call it *"output"*.

Now by using the quantum circuit we can make the *output* qubit depend on *input* qubit.

if $y=f(x)$ then $y$ depends on $x$.

The same thing can be done with bits:

Make some bit depend on another bit by using logic/boolean circuit/function.

Now the quantum computer modifies the *input* qubit so it starts at $x=0$ and changes state towards $x=1$ **gradually**.

At the same time that $x$ changes so $f(x)$ changes too, so the modification of *input* qubit also modifies the *output* qubit respectively.

The quantum computer will use third qubit that stores the maximum of $f$. The third qubit is initialized to zero and the state of *output* qubit is copied to the third qubit if and only if this operation will increase the value of the third qubit.

I think that this way the maximum of function $f$ can be found in O(1) constant time, maybe even 1 second.

Is my conjecture wrong?

Comment: -1 downvote for what?

Comment: Another -1 downvote, but for what!?

Comment: Don't bother on downvotes, make a lot of good answers. If you have some hundreds of rep (like you have on the SO), nobody will bother to harass you (because it is hopeless). However, if you complain against it on the meta, then you will likely get a lot of downs also on the meta, but the harassment on the main site significantly reduces. Another important thing: **listen what they say on the meta, and follow it, mostly you can find a good compromise between your wishes and theirs!**. Good luck!

Comment: @peterh you are good and kind person indeed and thank you for cheering me up, but I do**n't** bother on downvotes, but if someone downvotes my question then **there must be a reason that he/she did it. If you downvote then explain why you did this in a comment!** From downvotes I should learn lessons and be better both at asking and answering questions, but if you don't explain why you downvote then I learn **nothing** and I probably going to **repeat** my mistakes in the future. Do you agree with me? Am I right?

Comment: I agree. I posted about it something on the meta SE (I suggested that explained downs should be stronger). I got around 15 downs, and an incompetent ["answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298441/259412) from somebody who didn't even understand what I suggest. After that, I deleted the question in the last moment until I could (you can delete your own question if it doesn't have multiple answers or upvoted answer). Go to the meta, and ask them. Your survived questions don't seem very bad to me, I can't see your deleted ones, but seeing your reputation I think they were deeply downvoted.

Comment: Specifically, most of the sites have a negative side of their collective community behavior. On the SO, I think it is that the community wants to get rep, *but without actually helping you*. To get results, you have to fight them. The CS is not so bad, I think they simply don't believe that you are competent. It is much easier to deal with, get a lot of reputation by writing many good answers. So they will accept you. Also fighting on the meta helps on the main site (the price is that you get a lot downs on the meta, but it doesn't affect your reputation).

Comment: @peterh "It does**n't** affect my reputation"? When I joined meta, I started with 100 reputations, I asked 2 questions, the first got -6 and the second got -3. Now I see that I have 88 reputations and 88<100, so the downvotes **did** affect my reputations and decreased the number down by -12 (100-12=88). Also how should I fight them? How can I become competent? I also do**n't** like to fight and I do**n't** like to be competent.

Comment: It was the meta.stackexchange.com, on that site, yes there is rep. But it is a common meta site for the whole SE. The meta site specific to the cs.stackexchange.com is the cs.meta.stackexchange.com, on that site there is no question/answer ban and the downs don't affect your rep (on the CS SE). "Fight" don't mean real flamewar-ing, I understand only that if you find an evil/unjust behavior, you start a talk about it. Induvidual people are different, but the collective behavior of the communities is that they never retreat *in the specific case*, but they will be more lenient in the future.

Comment: @peterh "there is no question/answer ban" I did notice that even after having two bad questions with -9 in total I am still able to ask third question **un**like the other sites on the same network. In Stack Overflow for instance, having 2 bad questions blocks me from asking third question.

Comment: I made my SE "career" that I answered a lot posts first. Only much later asked I questions. You can get out from the answer ban if you edit your downvoted questions and then they get some ups (maybe 2 is already enough). There is probably also a timeout, maybe some months. Btw, I think the CS SE is really a hardcore site, not for us who made some CS courses in an MSc, but for people working with it every day. I think I could survive here, but I should dig deeply into hardcore CS questions for that. So I am satisfied with my $\approx$ 200 rep here and leave them in peace.

Comment: @peterh I don't care if I almost have zero reputations, the main and the only reason that I joined this community is to ask questions and get answers to get information that I ca**n't** find on the internet even if I try to google for it. Trust me If could find all the answers to my question with google I would**n't** join stack exchange and all it's networks **at all** from first place. This is **not** easy at all to ask a good question and I can't always ask questions without getting downvotes. I ca**n't** predict the future and know if this question will get downvoted or not.

Comment: I show you something. Another way to talk them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64157/discussion-between-peterh-and-erez-zrihen).

Comment: @peterh This is wrong to afraid to have downvotes, because if you afraid from this then you're not asking questions and get the answers that you want and this is very bad. I do**n't** care that my questions get downvoted, I am just do**n't** want to be in a state that I ca**n't** ask important questions anymore that their answers ca**n't** be found on google. I am very bothered that ban here is **permanent** and **not** temporary. I accept temporary ban for a **long** period, like 1 year, if I asked many bad questions, but not permanent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong.

First, you seem to be under the impression that you can say "hey, you qubits be the output of $f$ applied to these qubits" in some kind of permanent sense. Like, the output updates as the input is operated on. That's not how entanglement works. The best you can do is compute a superposition of many input/output pairs by applying $f$ to an input under superposition.

Second, you seem to think that you can do comparisons across different parts of the superposition or pull out information without weakening entanglement. You can't. You can interfere different parts of the superposition with each other, but that requires steps like uncomputing the input which you aren't taking into account.

Third, your algorithm has a step where "x changes gradually". That's a big red flag. In particular, this kind of thing always raises the question of "*how* gradually?". Does it have to get slower as the function get spikier? (Yes it always does.)

Fourth, there is a proof that no unstructured search over $N$ items can be done in less than $\Theta(\sqrt N)$ steps by a quantum computer. It's trivial to translate discrete search tasks into finding the maximum of an analytic function; your proposed $O(1)$ time bound is provably wrong before even looking at the details of your algorithm.

An example of a task somewhat similar to yours, that quantum computers can do faster than classical computers, is [computing the gradient of an $N$-dimensional function at a point with one evaluation instead of $N+1$ evaluations](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405146).

Comment: My $NP\subseteq BQP$ proof has been **failed!** Thank you for your **nice** answer. I will **believe** that $NP\nsubseteq BQP$ until it is proven otherwise.

Comment: @ErezZrihen, don't try to prove $BQP\subseteq NP$ as it would be even harder, I think.

Comment: @rus9384 Your comment implies that your conjecture in your question "satisfiability sufficient condition" is **false**, because if $P=NP$ then $NP\subseteq BQP \because P\subseteq BQP$ Also $BQP\subseteq NP$ is already true because $P\subseteq NP$. You meant $NP\subseteq BQP$, but **not** $BQP\subseteq NP$

Comment: @ErezZrihen, my comment implies nothing as it only states that simulating quantumness with non-determinism if it's possible, is not easy. If it's not possible, then proving this is even harder then $P\neq NP$. And $BQP$ vs. $NP$ is open problem. It's not known if they are comparable. It is not even known if $BQP\subset PH$.

Comment: I do**n't** know what is $PH$ at all and I do**n't** care about this at all. Are you telling me that **might** be exist a problem that classical computer can solve in polynomial time but quantum computer ca**n't** solve it in polynomial time? If so I prefer to **un**support the production of quantum computer and I do**n't** care about cryptography and it's serious and important unsolvable problems.

Comment: @ErezZrihen, there might be a problem that can be solved in poly-time by quantum Turing machine, but couldn't be solved in poly-time by NTM. Of course, this is not proven/disproven.

Comment: What is NTM at all?

Comment: @ErezZrihen Non-deterministric Turing-machine. In theory, it is a Turing-machine which can be a set of states, and not only in a state. You can think on it as a hyphotethical CPU with infinite cores.

Comment: NTM is an acronym for **N**on-deterministic **T**uring-**m**achine. Why did**n't** I get it? Thank you for pointing this out. I already know what is Non-deterministic Turing-machine, which does**n't** and wo**n't** be exist in reality never. By the way did you upvoted my question? Last time I visited this question, it had -2 score. Now I see -1. I am surprised.